# How to show div content on specific day of the week and spcific hours?

Tags: html, date, hide, show

Looking for solution to show div on specific hours and day of the week.
I already find something but i dont know how to modify it to show html content on specific day and hours:
- Monday - Thursday, from 10:00 to 22:30
- Friday - Saturday, from 10:00 to 24:30
- Sunday, from 11:00 to 21:30

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
function ShowOnTime(from, to, element){

    var a = new Date(); 
    var now = a.getHours(); //local hours. For GMT use .getUTCHours()

    if( now < from || now > to ){

        $(element).html("<br><h4>We are currently unable to process this order. </ h4> <p> Order can be placed only in: <ul><li>Monay - Thursday, from 10:00 to 22:30 </li> <li>Friday - Saturday, from 10:00 to 24:30  </li> <li> Sunday, from 11:00 to 21:30</li></ul>");
    }else{
        $(element).show();
    }

}


$(document).ready(function(){
    ShowOnTime(12,24,"#hide"); 
});
</script>
    <div id="hide">
  <div>
    Link  to proceed order, is visible only on specific hours and day of the week</div> 
  </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Arczix/hgt0ahmo/

Comment: would be better if you use some backends

Comment: Anyone can help me to improve this script?